# What creative ways have you exhibited your photos that led to more exposure?

Tags: marketing

I'm a serious hobbyist photographer and take pictures mostly for myself, but also love seeing my work used elsewhere.

Recently I was in a position to use a photo of mine at an annual neighborhood event. I used my photo on the cover of an HOA membership list that's used when people checked into the picnic. A local city councilman saw the photo and expressed interest in acquiring a print of the photo for use in in City Hall.

What are some of the off beat methods you've tried to give your photography more exposure?

Comment: Are you looking mainly for exposure / eyeballs or do you have a goal of that exposure leading to the most amount of $$$/revenue?

Comment: More opportunities, not necessarily for monetary purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what your goals are, of course, but I've found volunteering at a deserving charity that's in-line with what you want to be doing a good thing. If you want to focus on pets, volunteer at the local shelter taking photos of the current dogs and/or cats. Personally, I volunteer for my local Make-A-Wish chapter and do a few events for them.

Get some business cards (I like [Moo](http://www.moo.com)) and hand them out.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried hanging them at the lobby of my apartment building. And also I've tried showing them at bars and restaurants, and that's how a gallerist discovered the pictures and started showing them at the gallery.